# C++ do I have to initialize public instance member variable in constructor?

Tags: c++, initialization, member, public

my class has function pointer public instance member variable.(_base_func_ptr)
do I have to initialize '_base_func_ptr' in constructor?
or just skip initialize?

```
    class base_cls {
    public:
    #ifdef WHICH_ONE_IS_CORRECT

        base_cls():_base_func_ptr(nullptr), _some1(0), _some2(0) {}

    #else ifdef INITIALIZE_ORDER_IS_REVERSE

        base_cls():_some1(0), _some2(0), _base_func_ptr(nullptr) {}

    #else ifdef JUST_SKIP_INITIALIZE_PUBLIC_MEMBER

        base_cls():_some1(0), _some2(0){}

    #endif 

        void (*_base_func_ptr)(void);
    private:
        int _some1;
        int _some2;
    };
```

Comment: Fyi, the order of member initialization is *always* the declaration order within the containing class.The order you provide on the member-init list makes no difference. Regarding *not* initializing your member func-ptr, can you think of a reason *not* to? Is there *really* an upside to just leaving it dangling with an indeterminate value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't *have* to initialize it in the constructor but you must initialize it before the variable is used. Otherwise, your program will have undefined behavior.

Comment: plus 1 for being spot on. It is not necessary.